# Get variable value for its name in Groovy

Tags: groovy, gstring

I have the following variables defined:

```
def VAL1 = 'foo'
def VAL2 = 'bar'

def s2 = 'hello ${VAL1}, please have a ${VAL2}'
```

What is the easiest way to make this substitution work?
How could I build a GString from `s2` and have it evaluated?
(VALs and s2 are loaded from database, this snippet is only for demonstrating my problem.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `SimpleTemplateEngine` if you can get your variables into a Map?

```
import groovy.text.SimpleTemplateEngine

def binding = [ VAL1:'foo', VAL2:'bar' ]

def template = 'hello ${VAL1}, please have a ${VAL2}'

println new SimpleTemplateEngine().createTemplate( template ).make( binding ).toString()
```

---

**edit**

You can use the binding instead of the map, so the following works in the groovyconsole:

```
// No def.  We want the vars in the script's binding
VAL1 = 'foo'
VAL2 = 'bar'

def template = 'hello ${VAL1}, please have a ${VAL2}'

// Pass the variables defined in the binding to the Template
new SimpleTemplateEngine().createTemplate( template ).make( binding.variables ).toString()
```

Comment: my problem is that VAL1 and VAL2, .. VALn variables are not in a map. I do not even know their exact number.

Comment: @jabal Can you edit your question to give a better example?  If you don't know what variables you are getting, how do you know what template to use?

Comment: @jabal Added another possible solution, using the binding (where your variables should already be declared) as the Map for the template

Answer (score 1):

and what about :

```
def VAL1 = 'foo'
def VAL2 = 'bar'

def s2 = "hello ${VAL1}, please have a ${VAL2}".toString()
```

?

Note : notice the double quotes

Comment: Ok, but from the database I get a simple string, not a GString. That's why I used single quotes. I have to do the substitution after having this variable defined.. :-)